# Can't work out why widget contents disappear from admin

Tags: theme-development, widgets, admin

everytime I make a change to any widgets in admin they disappear - sometime just from admin, sometimes from the frontend and sometimes both.

I get them back by adding `update_option( 'sidebars_widgets', $null );` to the bottom of functions.php - then I can see them in admin as 'inactive widgets'. Then I manually re-add them all in admin - it's very frustrating!

I'm using Canvas with a custom child theme. I added a new widget area by adding

```
// Underhome widget area
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ){
  register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Underhome widget',
    'id' => 'underhome_widget',
    'description' => "A widget area underneath the home page content",
    'before_widget' => '<div id="underhome">',
    'after_widget' => '<div class="fix"></div></div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  ));
}
```

to functions.php

Then I created a page template and added

```
<!-- dislay the underhome widget -->
<?php if ( dynamic_sidebar('underhome_widget') ) : endif; ?>
```

I can't see anything wrong with this? maybe it is unrelated?

Anyway I'm totally stuck does anyone has any suggestions apart from changing career?

Comment: _"any suggestions apart from changing career"_ hehe ... yes, I have: Deactivate all plugins. Comment out everything in your child themes functions.php (add `return` at the beginning). Then reload and see if works. If it does, move the `return` down by one function. Reload > Move down > and so on until you got the conflicting function. Also check your `console` (in the dev tool bar).

Comment: morktron, [`WP_DEBUG`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=WP_DEBUG%20is%3aa) deserves some care. I've made a couple of [demotivators](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/2608) for ya ;)

Comment: nice work Brasofilo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely not anything you are doing wrong but, rather, a misbehaving plugin. There is a lot of ugly code out there that causes widget zones to freak out on the admin side.

Try killing all of your plugins first, do you still have the problem? If not, turn them back on a few at a time until you find the culprit.

If you have access to your PHP log, clear the log and refresh the page. Pull your log, get rid of all the PHP Strict Standards warnings that are everywhere since 3.6, and what's left probably contains your error.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right. So far it looks like the culprit is Woosidebars but I'll check with them and reward you with the correct answer if it turns out to be true :)

Comment: Trade out your debug lines in wp-config.php for the following and see what your debug log turns up: http://pastebin.com/Rhkkw6u6

Comment: In the end it turned out to be a bug in Woothemes's Woosidebars. If you create a new widget area and forget to name it then it creates a random slug number and loses the widget content everytime you go to admin. The solution is to re-name the slug :) - that took 3 days to find out!

Comment: Geez. Sidebars are easy to do manually Mork, Tadlock wrote up a great piece on them a few years back: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/11/08/sidebars-in-wordpress

Comment: Excellent thanks, that is a great resource, i've saved it for future reference :). I can easily create sidebars but I can't easily make them appear conditionally. I've been a Joomla developer for a long time and have finally realised Wordpress is better ;). But I do miss some things like in Joomla there is a great extension to conditionally display 'modules' - all point and click and no code - http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager

Comment: What kind of conditional are you trying to write? WordPress actually has a really powerful set of conditionals http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: Thanks that is a useful resource, at the moment I just need to display a different widget depending on if the user is logged in or not, I'm sure I can work it out using that resource, thanks

Comment: That or is_mobile() are usually a person's first exposure to conditionals. You're looking for this - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in - though I'd bet you already knew that :)